# Fit TextView under ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have 2 rows of "buttons" which are composed of a vertical `LinearLayout` of an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. The problem I'm having right now is trying to set the `ImageView` aspect ratio without hardcoding its dimensions.

I have already tried playing with the layout weights but it still forces the TextView to be partially cut off.

The xml structure I have is 2 horizontal `LinearLayouts` and each button is described above.

I've included a picture of my problem. You can see the first button is forcing the `TextView` out of the bounds. The rest of the buttons you see are hardcoded dimensions, but I don't want to do that because smaller screen sizes won't work.
[image]

Here is my layout for one button:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/setting_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="openSettings"
            android:src="@drawable/menu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/setting_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your desired result is. Do you want every `ImageView` to have the same width? The same height? Do you want to crop images or do you want to scale them? Is it ok for every "button" to have different sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Try using images with lower dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a RelativeLayout and setting the TextView as anchor for the image:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setting_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/setting_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/setting_text"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="openSettings"
        android:src="@drawable/menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```